# "Data Types a la carte" - injection on the right questions

Tags: haskell

I am looking at the code specified in this article: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~swier004/publications/2008-jfp.pdf, Data types a la carte.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}


data Expr f = In (f (Expr f))

data Val e = Val Int
data Add e = Add e e 
data Mul x = Mul x x

type IntExpr = Expr Val

type AddExpr = Expr Add


data ( f:+:g ) e = Inl (f e)| Inr (g e)

class (Functor sub, Functor sup) => sub :<: sup where
  inj :: sub a -> sup a

instance Functor sym => sym :<: sym where
  inj = id

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (Functor f, Functor g) => (f :<: (f :+: g)) where 
  inj = Inl

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (Functor f, Functor g, Functor h, f :<: g) => (f :<: (h :+: g)) where
  inj l = Inr (inj l)

addExample::Expr ( Val :+: Add )
addExample= In( 
               Inr( 
                   Add
                   (In (Inl (Val 118)  ) ) 
                   (In (Inl (Val 1219) ) ) 
                  ) 
               )
instance Functor Val where
  fmap f (Val x)=Val x

instance Functor Add where
  fmap f (Add e1 e2) = Add (f e1) (f e2)

instance Functor Mul where
  fmap f (Mul e1 e2) = Mul (f e1) (f e2)


instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (f :+: g) where
  fmap f (Inl e1) = Inl (fmap f e1)
  fmap f (Inr e2) = Inr (fmap f e2)

foldExpr::Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Expr f -> a 
foldExpr f (In t) = f (fmap (foldExpr f) t)

class Functor f => Eval f where
  evalAlgebra ::f Int -> Int

instance Eval Val where
  evalAlgebra (Val x) = x

instance Eval Add where
  evalAlgebra (Add e1 e2) = e1 + e2

instance Eval Mul where
  evalAlgebra (Mul e1 e2) = e1 * e2

instance (Eval f, Eval g) => Eval (f :+: g) where
  evalAlgebra (Inl x) = evalAlgebra x
  evalAlgebra (Inr y) = evalAlgebra y


eval::Eval f => Expr f -> Int
eval expr = foldExpr evalAlgebra expr

inject::(g :<: f) => g (Expr f) -> Expr f
inject = In . inj

val::(Val :<: f) => Int -> Expr f
val x = inject (Val x)

infixl 6 ⊕
(⊕):: (Add :<: f) => Expr f -> Expr f -> Expr f
x ⊕ y = inject (Add x y) 

infixl 7 ⊗
(⊗):: (Mul :<: f) => Expr f -> Expr f -> Expr f
x ⊗ y = inject (Mul x y)

xxx :: Int -> Expr (Val :+: (Mul :+: Add) ) 
xxx x = val 100 ⊗ val 5
```

I have trouble wrapping my head around the injection to the right. Two questions:

- Why is not declared like this: `instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} => (f :<: (g :+: f)) where ...` similar to the injection to the left.
- Second question, is the `inj = Inr . inj` calling itself recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is not declared like this: `instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} => (f :<: (g :+: f))` where ... similar to the injection to the left.

The way the original code uses makes an instance head strictly more specific than the other. That is: `f :<: (f :+: g)` is more specific than `f :<: (h :+: g)`, since the first only matches a (strict) subset of cases w.r.t. the latter.

This makes the compiler happy: the first instance can be tried. If it matches, great. If it does not match, and it does not unify, we can commit to the second more general instance. (If it does not match but unifies, then we are stuck and we can not commit to either instance.)

Doing it your way increases the possibility that constraint solving gets stuck, since when resolving `F :<: (F :+: F)` both instances apply. In original code, the first would be applied, since it is more specific.

> Second question, is the `inj = Inr . inj` calling itself recursively?

No. The last `inj` is that define by the instance for `f :<: g`, so it is a different function. This often happens, e.g.

```
-- pseudocode
instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) where
   show Nothing = "Nothing"
   show (Just x) = "Just " ++ show x
```

The last line calls the `Show a` method, and does not recurse.